# How do I draw this shape in css?

Tags: css, sass

I'm trying to draw this shape in scss. How do I do this?
[image: This shape]

Here's my attempt so far. Sorry, did not realize you needed to see my failed attempt: https://jsfiddle.net/5dy4Lwvf/

```
.shape {
  width: 114px;
    height: 167px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 114px 0 16px/0 167px;
    -moz-border-radius: 0 114px 0 16px/0 167px;
    border-radius: 0 114px 0 16px/0 167px;
    background-color: #000;
}
```

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried?

Comment: If you are really trying then show us your attempt. If not, you should go try.

Comment: You could use svg.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a white circle with a red shadow. Set this inside  a clipping div.

Hover the snippet to see the final result

```css
.base {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: solid 1px;
}
.inner {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: yellow;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 60px -30px;
  box-shadow: 20px 30px red;
}
.base:hover {
  border-color: transparent;
}
.base:hover .inner {
  background-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="base">
  <div class="inner">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Smart solution!

Answer (score 0):

```
<svg width="580" height="400" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
 <!-- Created with Method Draw - http://github.com/duopixel/Method-Draw/ -->
 <g>
  <title>background</title>
  <rect fill="#fff" id="canvas_background" height="402" width="582" y="-1" x="-1"/>
  <g display="none" overflow="visible" y="0" x="0" height="100%" width="100%" id="canvasGrid">
   <rect fill="url(#gridpattern)" stroke-width="0" y="0" x="0" height="100%" width="100%"/>
  </g>
 </g>
 <g>
  <title>Layer 1</title>
  <path id="svg_2" d="m-207.5,-278" opacity="0.5" stroke-width="1.5" stroke="#000" fill="#fff"/>
  <path stroke="#fff" id="svg_4" d="m319.5,86c43.86488,159 -39.77071,311 -36.03313,311c3.73758,0 254.15522,-1 253.53229,-1c0.62293,0 -39.36404,-286 -217.49916,-310z" stroke-opacity="null" stroke-width="1.5" fill="#ff0000"/>
 </g>
</svg>
```

Check out this svg!

Comment: Thanks but I'm looking for css

Comment: could you elaborate a little bit more, what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I want to create a css logo. It is comprised of three shapes which I can easily place with :before and :after. The other shapes are very easy to create with css. I just need to find a way to create this one. I included a link to a jsfiddle attempt.

Comment: have you taken a look at css clip-path yet? https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/c/clip/

Comment: Too much work. I think you're right, I'll just go with SVG.